# ZF2: Define URL http or https

Tags: php, url, ssl, https, zend-framework2

Here is my problem.
I have a few pages in my application who uses SSL, like the lggin page. When i am in the main page (who doens't have SSL), every link created by the view ( href=$this->url(...) ) is plain html, even the login page. On the other hand, when i am in the login page, every other links displays with https.

In the controller, i manipulate if the page uses SSL or not, that is OK. But i want to show the correct link for the user when he navigates through the site, https for ssl pages and http for non-ssl ones.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if you have HTTPS available, you should use it on any page. It is really against the web of trust when you have some pages available via HTTPS, but others not. Sure, you might enforce HTTPS on some pages (so there is no HTTP), but vice versa is always a bad idea.

That being said, you can create a `scheme` route. With the scheme you are able to specify HTTPS on some routes:

```php
'secure' => [
  'type'    => 'scheme',
  'options' => [
    'scheme'   => 'https',
    'defaults' => [
      // the usual stuff
    ],
  ],

  'may_terminate' => false,
  'child_routes'  => [
    // all your https routes here
  ],
],
```

Because some of these "secure" routes might be defined at vendor level (e.g. you use ZfcUser), you can use "prototyping" of routes. For example all ZfcUser routes should only be accessible via HTTPS. The "main" route of ZfcUser is `zfcuser`:

```
'router' => [
  'prototypes' => [

    // Define "secure" prototype to add to routes
    'secure' => [
      'type'    => 'scheme',
      'options' => ['scheme': 'https'],
    ],
  ],

  // Apply the scheme route to ZfcUser
  'routes' => [
    'zfcuser' => [
      'chain_routes' => ['secure'],
    ],
  ],
],
```

Prototyping "prepends" the `secure` route to `zfcuser`. So this makes `zfcuser` and all its childs a child-route of `secure`. Therefore, all `zfcuser` routes are defined with HTTPS.

When you've come this far: if you now assemble the routes, they will get HTTPS automatically. When you have a  route `login` inside the `secure` route of my first example, you get the url via `$this->url('secure/login');`.

In the second case (prototyping) you don't need to mention the prototype, just use `$this->url('zfcuser');` for the user's route.